# Example usage of Category within Logger component

Tags: logging, mule

Mule has a logging component with a category field.[image]

If this field is used the loggers look like the below

```
INFO  2015-07-20 14:37:14,566 [[api.customers.authentication.v1505].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] entrance: CorrelationID:3b012970-2e88-11e5-8f2c-74a920524153, Message:/api/customers/authentication/1 flow invoked
INFO  2015-07-20 14:37:14,567 [[api.customers.authentication.v1505].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processorLoggerMessageProcessor: CorrelationID:3b012970-2e88-11e5-8f2c-74a920524153, Message:Message received in impl_validateCustomerSub_Flow
```

In the above logger the 1st one has a custom category called entrance and the next one is just the default category

My question is can someone give a few examples when this is useful to use 
? ... how this could be used to better organize the loggers ... I know its there for a reason but not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Category in logger component, can use it in log4j.property file to different the logs.

Example: In the requirement. Suppose we need to capture multiple  details in different category level : payload , and  timestamp details( We dont want to logs all the INFO details in  the same, and it is going to be mess ).

We can differentiate as below by using category.

In the flow( Example), keep some two logger next to next , same level ( INFO), but different in category name ( Hello, audit). Only that particular logs will be logged in the specified location ( In log4j, Provide  two different location for both). In one location ( you can see only payload), and another location can see only TimeStamp.

```
    <logger message="****Capture Payload: #[message.payload]****" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" category="hello"/>
    <logger message="**Capture TimeSatmp:#[server.dateTime.getTime()]***" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" category="audit"/>
```

Need to update in the log4j Property file accordingly.

```
 #Category:hello Info 
 log4j.category.hello=INFO,LoggerInfo
 log4j.additivity.hello=false

 log4j.appender.hello=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.hello.File=c:/tmp/logger/hello.log
 log4j.appender.hello.MaxFileSize=4MB
 log4j.appender.hello.MaxBackupIndex=10
 log4j.appender.hello.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.hello.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

 #Category:audit Info 
 log4j.category.audit=INFO,audit
 log4j.additivity.audit=false

 log4j.appender.audit=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.audit.File=c:/tmp/logger/audit.log
 log4j.appender.audit.MaxFileSize=4MB
 log4j.appender.audit.MaxBackupIndex=10
 log4j.appender.audit.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.audit.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Can be used in multiple ways based on the requirement( Given above for just on example). Not sure about how this play a part in MMC.